# How to trigger google spreadsheet scripts through html box

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have few scripts in my spreadsheet say script1, script2, script3.

I usually recall them through different image that I have pasted in the spreadsheet. However, I want them all to appear on a HTML box and then from there I want to choose my script to run. Can anyone please help in this regard or write a little html script. I have no programming skills.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Sharad, If you have not programming skills perhaps stackoverflow is not the right place to find what you are looking for. Usually we ask to see what script you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: OK Thanks for the Help!